# Font size versus text scaling factor

Tags: unity, fonts

In Unity Tweak Tool, what is the difference between font size and text scaling factor?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I've found that too large a scaling factor can cause some tabs in Chrome or some label fields look "funny". On the other hand if I make the fonts too big they can seem ostentatious / overbearing. I just play with all settings until I find what's most comfortable. If you are afraid of playing around and making bad changes, write down the settings before you change them such that if you get cold feet you can rekey the old settings in. At the end of the day there are no objective answers because computers are subjective creatures. Have fun!

I just installed unity-tweak-tool last night and these are my settings for now (17" laptop screen 1920x1080HD 3-4 feet away and 55" TV 1920x1080HD 10 feet away):

[image: Tweak Tool]